# How to move all zones to a new Bind DNS Server

Tags: linux, unix, dns, bind, redhat

Existing Server = BIND version 9.1.3

new Server = BIND version 9.3.4

How can i move all zones records to new server? I tried moving them by coping the files and changing configuration file on new to match and zones did not resolve, no resolution.

Is there an smooth way to just transfer all zones to this new server?

Comment: "It didn't work" is forbidden on StackOverflow. It provides no useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying the files and updating the configuration is the right way to do this.

Using AXFR (zone transfer) is no good:

1. You still have to create a config file at the new server listing all of the zones, there's no way to say "transfer every zone".
2. The files you get out will be in a different order to the records in the originals, with any comments etc missing.  If you normally hand-craft your zone files this would be pretty annoying.

Please expand on "it didn't work" so that we can establish why not.

Answer (score 0):

What about setting up zone transfer by making your new server a slave of the old one? In that way the new server will pick up the data from the old one, after which you could probably break the master-slave relationship.